# Get executionId in Maven

Tags: java, maven, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-junit, maven-failsafe-plugin

I have an execution section inside a `maven-failsafe-plugin` declaration in my `pom.xml`.

```
<execution>
    <id>execId</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>integration-test</goal>
        <goal>verify</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration>
        <includes>
            <include>**/*LauncherIT.java</include>
        </includes>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

`LauncherIT` uses a custom cucumber runner.

```
@RunWith(CustomCucumber.class)
@io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions(
    plugin = {"json:target/cucumber.json"}
)
public class LauncherIT {
}
```

Is there a way to access execution id (and get `"execId"` value) in `customCucumber.java` at runtime?
I know that it is possible to define a system variable inside the execution and write `"execId"` into it, but I want to exactly read the execution id.

Comment: The execution Id is only available from within a maven plugin ...but not in your tests. The question is: Why do you need the `execId` in your Tests?

Comment: @khmarbaise because I'm using jenkins, and after a build there is some results provided by cucumber plugin, which are named by their feature files. Some feature files run more than once (with different options set in executions), so in the end I have some reports with the same name, and I do not know what execution produсed the specific report. So, I need the id to add it to default reports name.

Comment: AFAIK if you need something inside the plugin run, you must put into some parameter in the `<configuration>`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand this correctly, you can set the report file names through the parameters `<summaryFile>` or `<reportNameSuffix>` of the execution. So just put the name there.

Comment: My bad, I forgot to say that I work with reports generated by cucumber `JSONFormatter`. So `<summaryFile>` or `<reportNameSuffix>` aren't suitable, because it works with failsafe reports.